# unable to install MySql Workbench

Tags: linux, fedora, mysql

When I try to install [MySql Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/) using the yum command :

```
yum install mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686.rpm
```

I get these errors :

```
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
       Requires: /bin/python
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
       Requires: libzip.so.2
Error: Package: mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686 (/mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686)
       Requires: libctemplate.so.2
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

*What are these errors and what do I do to install this `MySql` GUI tool ?*

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Fedora 16. I also tagged fedora

Answer (score 1):

It tells you that no python is installed on the system since the `/bin/python` is missing.

1. Install python or create a symbolic link to existing python installed location.

   ```
   ln -s /usr/bin/python /bin/python
   ```
2. Use `yum whatprovides libzip.so.2` and see what package provides this library. Same for the other library

NOTE: You should install the `.rpm` package using the RPM package manager command and not yum. e.g.

> rpm -Uvh mysql-workb....rpm

`-U` is for update, `-I` for install

Comment: what difference does it make if I use `yum` or `rpm` to install rpm package ?

Comment: Yum queries the dependencies of a certain package. It's the law that says: .rpm packages are installed/deployed using Redhat Package Manager. If you wanted to use yum, don't add the version and the .rpm extension just `yum install mysql-workbench-gpl` It will then search for all required dependencies and install them along with the mysql-workbench. This is preferrable of course.

Comment: On entering the command it gives me this message : `No package mysql-workbench-gpl available.
Error: Nothing to do` What do **I** do now ? !

Comment: You need to get mysql-workbench-gpl from mysql website. But to install it you need other dependencies which is python. First install python using yum and then those other 2 libraries. E.g.  `yum install python2.7`  To install packages which provide those two libraries you run `yum whatprovides *libzip.so.2*`  and `yum whatprovides *libctemplate.so.2*` After performing these steps last thing to do is `rpm -Uvh mysql-workbench-gpl-5.2.45-1fc17.i686.rpm`

Comment: I have installed python from the tgz package. first unpacking it,then running the `./configure` command,then `make` and finally `make install` command. I see the same message again. There was already python 2.7 installed. I installed 3.3 now

Comment: What does `type python` say?  Is it located in /bin/python?  Since you compiled it, it certainly isn't. You can easily make a symlink so python points to /usr/bin

Comment: It gives me `python is /usr/bin/python`

Comment: try `ln -s /bin/python /usr/bin/python` and give it another try.

Comment: `ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/bin/python': File exists` get this message when I try the above command

Comment: Allright. Let's do it this way. 1) First clean up python you compiled from source. 2) Install python using `yum`. 3) Try again installing mysql-workbench.

Comment: Correction. it should be `ln -s /usr/bin/python /bin/python`

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install a package for Fedora 17 on Fedora 16. This isn't guaranteed to work, since the package versions for the package's dependencies may change from one version to the next. These dependencies do exist on my Fedora 17 box, though at least one of them appears to be different or missing on Fedora 16.

You have three options:

1. The preferred option: Upgrade to Fedora 17 or Fedora 18 (which is being released a few days from now). Fedora 16 will be EOL'd a month after the release of Fedora 18. After upgrading, you can then install the package.
2. Find the equivalent RPM for Fedora 16 and install it.
3. If no such RPM exists, rebuild the package on your system from the source RPM.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [mysql-workbench](http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=10989) available from the standard Fedora 16 repositories:

```
yum install mysql-workbench
...
Installed:
  mysql-workbench.x86_64 0:5.2.45-1.fc16
```